# How to solve apt-update providing with Error in ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, update-manager

I had tried to install sosumi A few days back. I haven't used my pc since then and now after i try to run `sudo apt update`, this shows up:

```
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Hit:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease     
Ign:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Ign:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Err:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done                              
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried several fixes, but nothing worked. Any solutions?

Comment: *I tried several fixes, but nothing worked.* If so those weren't fixes. The only fix is to remove the PPAs mentioned in the error message. Neither has content for Ubuntu 22.04. The way to avoid this in the future is to NOT follow old instructions that include adding PPAs without making sure they support your release.

Answer (score 3):

You have two PPA's which do not have releases for Jammy:

> https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu
> https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu

You should edit the corresponding file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` to reference `focal` instead of `jammy` for these PPA's (this may or may not work as expected). Or you can disable them entirely with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mc3man/xerus-media
```

Comment: now i am getting this - The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 22.04 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220419) jammy Release' does not have a Release file.